# Loudness equalization/correction

Tags: audio, equalizer

Some people say that loudness correction controls the levels over different frequencies (like a bandpass), while others say that loudness correction make explosions and whispers on a movie the same level.

By level I mean what we call volume

I need this last one on my Windows (to make explosions and whispers on a movie the same level), so I don't have to keep rolling the mouse wheel up and down a hundred times during a 45 minute movie.

But it's quite hard when I see no consensus on the area.

- I tried enabling that Windows default enhancement, but no difference.
- MPC-HC has this *Normalize* thing, that doesn't do anything other than amplify everything
- I have this Equalizer APO software, that has a loudness thing...
  But since I'm here, you know the result

Anything definitive about the matter ?

Comment: What you are looking for is a compressor, a limitier or a combination of both.

Comment: What you're looking for is known as a multi-band compressor. idk any that will sit in Windows APO structure, sorry. Usually, they are available as VST, AU, etc as plugins to more 'pro' audio environments. I know how you could do this on Mac, very easily but not free.

Comment: https://voicemeeter.com seems to have a bus limiter

Comment: You can also play audio through an app such as VLC or Audacity, which have limiting, volume normalization (with variable attack and decay setting), equalization, etc.  You can also process and save existing files to your preferences.

Comment: Thank you all for the answers. Knowing now that compression is what I needed, I went after some lightweight apps that promised that. Found a good one, but may need some help. https://superuser.com/questions/1738523/viper4windows-tutorials

Answer (score 1):

quote:
"I need this last one on my Windows (to make explosions and whispers on a movie the same level), so I don't have to keep rolling the mouse wheel up and down a hundred times during a 45 minute movie"

Using various MPC-HC settings on diff. machines, I control my similar issue here:

`MPC-HC (64-bit) 1.7.9 > Options\Internal Filters\Audio Switcher\ "Enable custom channel mapping"`

And set proper input channels according to hardware. (changes of cables whilst MPC-HC is running will cause HDMI and/or optical connection to **re-set unwanted defaults**).

In a 5.1 environment, the dialogs come mainly to center clear to understand, whilst other sounds are "surrounding you".

When (by default) mixed into stereo you suffer with the scroll wheel...  time to check again and set proper input again.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I'll thumbs up for the effort, but indeed, doesn't solve the problem. All the 6 channels are "balanced". Louds and lows